# regression approach for missing data (left censoring?)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, survival, censoring

I have a regression problem where I want to predict actuals (dependent variable) of some process where I only have values for a small number of independent variables at the beginning of the process but more non missing data as the process matures. This is kind of similar to survival analysis, which I have used in the past, but with left censoring. However, in contrast to survival analysis I want to predict the value of a continuous variable instead of a (survival) probability. Are there specific regression approaches I can use (e.g. truncated regression, censored regression)? Any pointers, especially to R/Python packages, would be very much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure I completely understand your setting, but for censored regression you can use the `survreg()` function from the **survival** package in R.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is not clear so that I can improve my question? Btw can survival analysis not only be used to predict hazards/probabilities. In my case, I would like to predict a continuous variable as in regression ...

Comment: I also cast the problem differently here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371675/censored-regression-problem-if-dependent-variable-only-above-threshold

Comment: The `survreg()` function can be used for censored regression. Hazard ratios and survival probabilities are more natural in the Cox models framework fitted by `coxph()`. Though, of course, because the hazard function is linked to the density and survival functions. Even if you fit the model with `survreg()` you could, in principle, calculate the hazard.